# How to run a method in another thread in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, methods

I have a MainActivity class in Android that loads first screen. When starting, I need to run another method in another thread and then either show message or go to another screen. For UI not to hang.
How to do this? In which place of code?

// UPDATED CODE

```
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Context context=getApplicationContext();
    String Internet=String.valueOf(isNetworkAvailable(this));
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, Internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) 
{
    return ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

}

Comment: AsyncTask might help you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: you can use `thread` or `asynctask`. you need to be more specific.

Comment: @Raghunandan - no, they don't need to be more specific as either solution will work fine.

Comment: @Raghunandan - a service is not by itself a solution as a service does not automatically imply a different thread (though of course a service can be explicitly written so that it will utilize a background thread).  Using a handler for the UI update has already been mentioned in Romiox's answer, and the runOnUiThread alternative by DigCamara.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes. you will have a create thread for the service. i deleted my previous comment as i just realized about what you said.

Comment: Thanks. This case is rather simple. But what if I must run music after loading UI? Must it be in a separate thread?

Comment: @user2543953 - probably, unless you can use some set source and forget type API. And if you want the music to span across various Activities you may want to put that thread in a service.

Comment: @user2543953 in that case use service . http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html. Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process.

Answer (score 5):

You can go the Java route and utilize a normal Thread. Note, however, that you will need a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) (class located in the Android SDK) to propagate your changes to the UI.
The more Android-kind-of way would be an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). It is designed specifically for tasks that have to run in parallel to the UI and provides a mechanism to call back to the UI, so you don't have to implement that yourself (exactly what you would do with the handler if you decide to choose the furst option).

Comment: you can use runOnUiThread to propagate your changes to the UI as well.

Comment: Now I'm trying firstly to Toast the result of checking the connection in onCreate method:
String Internet=String.valueOf(this.isNetworkConnected());
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Internet, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
  toast.show();

But it stops the app. How I can right call isNetworkConnected() method here?

Comment: Now code is updated. I've updated Internet checking method name and implementation.

Comment: @user2543953 do you this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` in manifest?.

Comment: I haven't used it recently, but I believe you have to pass `this` or `MainActivity.this` as Context to the Toast. (But I am really not too sure about it, sorry)

Comment: @user2543953 also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context

Comment: I remember to have added this to manifest, but now when adding and saving, this disappears some way.

Comment: The changes in SDK are not visible in FAR Manager. Also when exporting to .apk, this permissions disappear %)

Comment: Thanks! Now seems to be working after adding directives and changing context to this. Need to test without Internet, would it write false. And then do another thread... but Internet checks rather fast... The bug is why permissions are not saved properly sometimes.

Comment: @user2543953 that has nothing to do with your code may be the editor causing the problem. i am talking about permissions not saving.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But the problem was I added this permission earlier, but later it disappeared. After adding one more time it works. Before it didn't either ask about them when installing on the phone. Thanks.

Comment: So if the Internet check consumes little time - there is no reason to add it to another thread? Or in some situations the check can be durable?